# Plotting function g(v) against p(v)

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, matlab

I have a function g(v) which is Gibbs free energy and another function which is p(v) which is described by Vanderwaal's model. Anyway I need to plot g as a function of v but I am unsure of how to do it, they are both related as they are functions of v but I tried and failed to rearrange p(v) in terms of v(p) because there is a polynomial sort of term $v^2 + v$. The functions are $p = \frac{8.t}{3.v-1}-\frac{6}{v^2}$ where t can be treated as a constant. and, $g = \frac{8.t}{3}.ln(3.v-1) - \frac{8t}{9v-3}-\frac{6}{v}+c(t)$ where c(t) is a constant, which is a function of t (but since we are holding t constant it is just a constant)
Here is the matlab code for the formulas:
'''t = 0.95;
v = 0.5:0.0001:3;
g = ((8/3)*t).*log((3.*v)-1)+(8/3).*t./((3.*v)-1)-6./v;
p = (8*t)./(3.*v-1) - 3./v.^2;'''
I am trying to make the graph look like the following: [image]

Comment: It is just a parametric plot. Do not try to rearrange anything.

Comment: when I plot it with the normal plot(x,y) function it doesn't look like that, I don't know what a parametric plot is, I'll looks it up.

Comment: I'm just really not sure how I can get a graph like that with the given functions.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/155224-help-plotting-parametric-equations

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried that and it did not give me a parametric plot, must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot use a parametric plot function, since the calculations will be very fast, do the following

- assign a value to $V$ and compute $P$ from the equation of state. We do not care if $P <0$
- using this $V$ compute $G$
- Now, you have a table $(V_i,P_i,G_i)$

Comment: I apologize, I had left a minus sign off of the first term in the gibbs function when I derived it and that was the reason I was not getting a parametric function. I guess I should ensure I have done the basics correctly before getting too complicated. Thank you for your help regardless!